# Let $S \subseteq \mathbb Z$, prove that if $0∈S$, and $k∈S$ implies $k+1∈S$ and $k-1∈S$, then $S=\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, induction, integers

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb Z$, prove that if $0∈S$, and $k∈S$ implies $k+1∈S$ and $k-1∈S$, then $S=\mathbb Z$

My intended approach is to convert this question into another form where I can do 2 mathematical inductions. One for $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$ and another for $P(k)$ implies $P(k-1)$.

However, since mathematical induction only work to prove $P(n)$, where $n∈ \mathbb N$, I am having trouble establishing the premises for these 2 inductive statements.

So, any possible proposed solution?

Comment: Let P (k) be "k in S".  Let Q (k) be "-k in S".  We are given the base case and the induction step.  So P and Q are both true for all natural k.  So N subset S.  And -N subset S.  So N union -N = Z subset S.  So Z subset S and S subset Z.  So S =Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction that for $n\in\Bbb N$, if $n\in S$ and $-n\in S$, then both $\pm (n+1)\in S$.